# Dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 18.04 on Gigabyte B560 DS3H AC mobo

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I picked up a prebuilt CyberPowerPC from Amazon on Black Friday for machine learning and crypto mining.  I need to install Ubuntu to be able to use it for ML (and rent it to other researchers when I'm not using it: https://vast.ai/).

I followed this guide, plus a few other guides and YouTube videos to confirm/fill in gaps:

https://www.xda-developers.com/dual-boot-windows-11-linux/

I used Rufus to create what I believe is a bootable FAT32 USB with the 18.04 ISO, and I made a new SSD partition.  In the Gigabyte UEFI, I have disabled secure boot, enabled CSM, and set the parameters under CSM to UEFI wherever applicable.  I also tried telling the UEFI to regard attached USB devices as hard drives.  Regardless, when I try to boot from the Linux USB, I get a black screen that says

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key
```

I can provide more info if necessary, e.g. pics of my BIOS configurations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows 11 requires Secure Boot enabled and doesn't support CSM/Legacy at all. If using Rufus you must select UEFI/GPT options before burning. And don't use an almost 4 years old release for brand new hardware.

Comment: Thanks!  Incidentally, I am able to boot into Windows 11 just fine whether or not CSM is enabled.  Yes, I selected the GPT option in Rufus before burning.  And unfortunately, my use case requires 18.04 LTS specifically.

Comment: Another excellent reference I used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezubjTO7rRI

Comment: CSM enabled or disabled, unless it's "CSM only" doesn't matter, the point is having UEFI mode enabled. And there's absolutely NO POINT in enabling CSM in 2021.

Comment: When I disabled CSM, the bios didn’t see the USB *at all*… but I’ll take your word for it. (FWIW, the official guide at Canonical uses MBR rather than GPT, but I tried both and neither worked: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#6-write-the-iso)  I’m happy to send a screenshot of my Rufus settings if you think I should try reburning the USB.

Comment: It’s become a game of flipping binary switches in Rufus and the BIOS trying to find what combination makes the board happy.  Per your original comment, next one I’ll try is CSM off, Secure Boot on, GPT/UEFI on in Rufus.

Comment: Is it  Rocket Lake CPU? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1905466 You need newest kernel & drivers. And make sure you have newest UEFI for your motherboard. If you must run 18.04, better to just find an old used system from about 2017 that then would work really well with 18.04.

Comment: Thank you @oldfred.  Yes, it is an 11400F.  Thanks for the bug report, there’s no way I would have known about that.  It looks like this bug was not fixed until Fossa; does that mean there’s no way I can install 18.04 on this machine?  (Interestingly, 18.04 installs and runs just fine in the WSL inside Windows 11.). At any rate, I’ll try flashing the mobo.

Regarding older hardware: I got this system for the RTX 2060 GPU, mainly.  Not sure if that would run well with older HW in general.

Comment: I dual boot multiple Linux installs, mostly Ubuntu & flavors as partitioned installs. But see many post about using VM. That does isolate some hardware. No idea if that would work or not? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2459660&page=2

Answer (score 0):

I was NOT able to dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 18.04.  This is because Rocket Lake processors don't support legacy/MBR booting, and Windows 11 restricts UEFI bootloaders from having Level 0 access to disk memory on the disk where W11 is installed. The Ubuntu installer crashes because it can't write the OS files to disk.  Therefore, Windows 11 and Ubuntu 18.04 cannot be installed on the same hard disk.

I solved my problem by installing Ubuntu on a different disk, a 256gb USB 3.0 flash stick.  Important settings were as follows:

- In Rufus, select GPT partitioning scheme, not MBR, since Rocket Lake doesn't support MBR.
- In your BIOS, turn off CSM and Secure Boot. As noted in the comments, CSM is not supported. If Secure Boot is on, the motherboard will only see the Windows disk.

Obviously, I'm just restating what others have told me over the past 2 days.  If anyone has a clearer idea of the "why" aspects, please comment and I will edit my answer.

I would like to acknowledge the help of the commenters on the original question, a very knowledgeable worker in the WalMart electronics section (thanks, Jacob), and a friendly and experienced guy in the vast.ai host [discord](https://discord.gg/UaRdT98) (thanks, Marc).